# window.onpopstate not triggered after page reload

Tags: javascript, django, html, html5-history

I have two basic pages with the urls

`http://localhost:8000/page-a` and

`http://localhost:8000/page-b`.

I'm using html5 `history api` and following [this](https://html5doctor.com/history-api/) tutorial.

The only difference is that I add the api endpoint of the data, like

`http://localhost:8000/api/page-a` and

`http://localhost:8000/api/page-b`, in `pushState()`.

I can easily go back and forth in history but when reloading the page and go back and forth, `window.popstate` does not trigger anymore. Rather, it directly navigates to `page-a` and `page-b` as it says in the console.

In the [demo](https://html5doctor.com/demos/history/), I reloaded the pages but it still works fine. Is this because the data has to be fetched with AJAX? (but in the tutorial it says the AJAX is fine)

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the pages are created dynamically (with Django). Is it because of the dynamic nature of the pages?

---

**SOLVED**

I should have added the url of the state like `http://localhost:8000/api/page-a/`. On page reload, Django always resolves the url `http://localhost:8000/page-a` to `http://localhost:8000/page-a/` so when I click the back button the `onpopstate` is never triggered. It was just a '/' and costed me like two days.